# How Make Cell Read Only in DataGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i have data grid view get data from database 

i have validation to edit in all grid 

but i have some cells I need to prevent editing on it upon some 
condition i put it when filling this grid
how can focus on cell and prevent editing on it

Comment: Delphi 7 or Delphi 2010? Or does it not matter? We use version tags to indicate which version the question applies to.

Comment: Delphi doesn't have a *data grid view*. Do you mean `TDBGrid`?

Comment: @ David Heffernan  Delphi 7 
@ Ken White yes i mean TDBGrid

Comment: If you would install Jedi CodeLib and then JediVCL then you can use `procedure TForm1.DBGrid1_OnCanEditCell(Grid: TJvDBGrid; Field: TField; var AllowEdit: Boolean);` event